# Python - Reading PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, text-extraction

I have a few pdf files, i want to extract texts from, i have used just about all the libraries associated with it like pyPDF2, pdfminer. Even went ahead with tesseract and imagemagick. Imagemagick blackens most of the pdf page in the converted jpg format, which then isn't read by tesseract.

The problem is, that while the texts/paragraphs are being extracted, the library isn't extracting whole of it. For example, in some pdf files, the entire text is being extracted, while in other pdf files, a few lines out of the entire paragraph are only being extracted.

I want to know, if there is any other way through python to extract texts? 
I was however able to extract all of the text, when i converted the pdf to jpg from an online source, and then used tesseract on the converted jpg files. However, that method isn't really feasible.

Comment: What version of ImageMagick? Was it CMYK rather than RGB colorspace for your PDF? Did you make the density large enough. Did you turn off any alpha channel?  Try `convert -density 300 -colorspace RGB image.pdf -alpha off image.jpg` However, JPG is lossy compression, so you might consider making the output PNG or TIF

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you flatten your image, specify the background as white, as well as use some other protocols that were specified in the command line documentation.  There are tons of options to play with.  I have found good results with this, though in your circumstances may be different.

You are going to want to check the output until it looks satisfactory enough to be read by the OCR.

```
magick -colorspace gray filename.ppm  
-density 300 -depth 8 -flatten -auto-orient -auto-level -rotate -90> output.tif
```

For more help, please check [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try [pdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/) to extract texts (plain and containing PDF operators) and images (inline & XObject) from PDF document

Here is a sample code extracting all the above from all document pages.

```
from pdfreader import SimplePDFViewer, PageDoesNotExist

fd = open(you_pdf_file_name, "rb")
viewer = SimplePDFViewer(fd)

plain_text = ""
pdf_markdown = ""
images = []
try:
    while True:
        viewer.render()
        pdf_markdown += viewer.canvas.text_content
        plain_text += "".join(viewer.canvas.strings)
        images.extend(viewer.canvas.inline_images)
        images.extend(viewer.canvas.images.values())
        viewer.next()
except PageDoesNotExist:
    pass
```

You can convert images to [PIL/Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) object and save (or do whatever you need)

```
for i, img in enumerate(images):
    img.to_Pillow().save("{}.png".format(i))
```